# WifiNetWorkSpecifier NOT WORKING WHEN I TRY TO CONNECT TO WIFI IN ANDROID 10 Q API 29

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

This is my code used for connecting wifi in android 10
When i tried this code onAvailable is called and wifi is not connected
*i use honor 8x device*
Using this didn't change anything in behavior.

Please let know sequence of APIs to connect successfully to different Wifi AP with internet capability.

```
 final NetworkSpecifier specifier =
                new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
                        .setSsid(ssd)
                        .setBssid(MacAddress.fromString(bssid))
                        .setWpa2Passphrase(password)
                        .build();

        final NetworkRequest request =
                new NetworkRequest.Builder()
                        .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
                        .removeCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
                        .setNetworkSpecifier(specifier)
                        .build();

        final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
                getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        final ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback networkCallback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onAvailable(Network network ) {
                // do success processing here..

                    
                    super.onAvailable(network);

                connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network);
                loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                isConnectionCreated = true;
                TabLayout.Tab tab = tabs.getTabAt(0);
                tab.select();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onUnavailable() {
                // do failure processing here..
                super.onUnavailable();
                isConnectionCreated = false;
                loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Something went wrong!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        };
        connectivityManager.requestNetwork(request, networkCallback);
```